# Redshift WLM - how are unused slots used

Tags: amazon-redshift

My understanding of WLM in Redshift is that there are queues and each queue has slots (by default 5). And let's say the system is idle, and I run a query. By default it occupies one slot and runs the query, even though other slots are free and available. Right ?

If so, is it not a waste of resources to let other slots remain idle and not do any work when they can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that's pretty much how Redshift WLM works.

For example if it's configured with one queue and that queue has five slots each with 20% of memory then your one query is by default going to run in one slot and use up to 20% memory max. The rest of the slots will sit idle waiting for another query to hit the same queue.

However, you can override the default behaviour, e.g. by specifying `wlm_query_slot_count` as 2 the query will use two slots instead of one, and therefore up to 40% of memory.

e.g.

```
set wlm_query_slot_count to 2;
select * from public.mytable;
```

Be careful doing this though as if you up the slot count to 5 (in this example) then no other queries will be able to run as there are now no available slots. This is not quite true if **short query acceleration** (SQA) is enabled on the cluster, as in that case very short queries (typically 5 seconds or less) will be run in a special hidden queue if there are no normal slots available.

Many cluster WLM configurations will have more than one queue, maybe one or two with few slots and therefore a higher resource-to-slot ratio that can be used for a smaller number of resource hungry tasks like data loads and updates, and some with more slots with a lower amount of resources per slot. Those queues will typically be used by BI and analytics tools to query the data.

You can also use [WLM Query Queue Hopping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/wlm-queue-hopping.html) to manage queries that end up waiting for slots to become free by diverting them to a different queue. Also bear in mind that "concurrency" and "percent of memory" are *dynamic* WLM configuration properties and you can change them using the CLI ([ModifyClusterParameterGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/APIReference/API_ModifyClusterParameterGroup.html)) without having to restart the cluster, e.g. reallocate resources from a data load queue to an analytics queue once all data has been loaded.